# Mean Value Theorem Proofing For all $ x>0$

Tags: calculus

By applying the Mean Value Theorem to the function $f(t)=e^t$ defined on the interval $[0, x]$, where $x > 0$, show that for all $x > 0$, $e^x>1+x$.

What I have done...

$f(t) = e^t$
$f$ is continuous on $[0,x]$ and differentiable on $(0,x)$.

For at least one $C$ in domain $(0,x)$ such that
$(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a) = f'(C)$

$(e^0 - e^x)/(-x) = e^c$

$1-e^x = -xe^c$

How do I continue the proof from here?

Comment: What I have done...

f(t) = e^t
f is continuous on [0,x] and differentiable on (0,x)

For at least one C in domain (0,x) such that
(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a) = f'(C)

(e^0 - e^x)/(-x) = e^c

1-e^x = -xe^c

How do i continue proofing from there?

Comment: Then what have you done?

Comment: What do you get when you simply apply the mean value theorem? Also do you 'know' that $e^x$ is an increasing function also? Because those two facts give what you want straightaway

Comment: @user222180 Welcome to stackexchange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, we have $c\in[0,x]$ such that

$f(x)-f(0)=f'(c)(x-0)$

That is, $e^x-1=e^cx$

Since $e^x$ is increasing and $c>0$ then $e^c>e^0=1$

Thus $e^x-1=e^cx>x$ and thus $e^x>1+x$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: f'(c) is greater than 1, c in (0,x).